# SpriteKit Node Rotational Issues

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am trying to develop a basic game for iOS involving a rag doll-like entity. Basically (as you can tell below), I have a head, a body, and a right arm (all three are basic sprite nodes) connected via pin joints, simulating joins in the human body (roughly).

The head and the body work perfectly in that, when a force is applied, the body rotates around the head perfectly and eventually comes to a rest under the head, vertically (see picture).

The arm's base is pinned with a pin joint to the body and is supposed to rotate around its base (kind of like a shoulder) and it is set with an initial rotation of 45 degrees so it looks like an arm before the physics engine takes over.

My question is: why doesn't the arm come to rest in a vertical position (like the body) due to gravity? Shouldn't gravity cause the arm to rotate about its base until the tip of the arm rests directly below the top of the arm (shoulder)? Furthermore, when a force is applied to the body (shown in the example code below), the body rotates about the neck joint, exactly as it should, but the arm does not move from its current orientation (and this is not desirable).

If this is not the case, how would I achieve this effect?

Thank you for your time and I'd be happy to provide any additional information if desired

Picture of physics simulation at rest:
[image]

Relevant code which demonstrates the problem:

```
//make the head node
SKSpriteNode *head = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"head"];
head.size = CGSizeMake(20 * [CFLConstants universalWidthScaleFactor], 20 * [CFLConstants universalWidthScaleFactor]);
head.position = position;
head.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:head.size.width/2];
head.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CFLPhysicsCategoriesHead;
head.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
head.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[self.ragdollLayer addChild:head];

//make the body node
SKSpriteNode *body = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"body"];
body.size = CGSizeMake(head.size.width, head.size.width * 3);
body.position = CGPointMake(head.position.x, head.position.y - head.size.height/2 - body.size.height/2);
body.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:body.size];
body.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CFLPhysicsCategoriesBody;
body.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
[self.ragdollLayer addChild:body];

//attach the head and the body (via a neck joint)
SKPhysicsJointPin *neckJoint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:head.physicsBody bodyB:body.physicsBody anchor:CGPointMake(head.position.x, head.position.y - head.size.height/2)];
[self.physicsWorld addJoint:neckJoint];

//make the right arm
SKSpriteNode *rightArm = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"arm"];
rightArm.size = CGSizeMake(head.size.width/5, head.size.width/5 * 10);
rightArm.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
CGPoint rightArmPosition = CGPointMake(body.position.x + body.size.width * 1/5, body.position.y + body.size.height * 1/5);
rightArm.position = rightArmPosition;
rightArm.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rightArm.size];
rightArm.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CFLPhysicsCategoriesRightArm;
rightArm.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
rightArm.zRotation = -M_PI_4;

//force which makes the arm problem even more noticeable
[body.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(100, 0)];
[self.ragdollLayer addChild:rightArm];

//make the joint which holds the right arm to the body, but should allow the arm to rotate about this point (and doesn't)
SKPhysicsJointPin *rightShoulderJoint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:body.physicsBody bodyB:rightArm.physicsBody anchor:rightArmPosition];
[self.physicsWorld addJoint:rightShoulderJoint];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this is because changing the anchor point on the sprite, doesn't change the anchor point for the physics body. Though I swear sometimes you don't have to, so maybe it's an order of operations thing. But anyways, offset the center of the physics body to account for the sprite anchor point. Something like:

```
spriteRightArm.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);

spriteRightArm.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:spriteRightArm.size center:CGPointMake(spriteRightArm.size.width/2, -spriteRightArm.size.height/2)];
```

Comment: and then if you just want to test the arm spinning versus gravity, use `applyTorque:` on the arm's physicsBody.

Comment: I had a similar problem but unfortunately this solution didn't work for me :(. Turning on the physics debug mode so I could see the outlines of the physics bodies, I have ensured that the rectangle is in the proper place. I have my own questions posted here about this so I won't go into it here. I've been using SpriteKit for over a year now and I'm getting pretty disappointed in it now because of issues like this that affect core gameplay.

Comment: The system works correctly, but that doesn't mean it isn't confusing. Just make sure you understand how anchor points relate to objects being added to the scene as well as the coordinate systems you're working with and you'll likely figure out your issue.